# Распространение Docker-образов

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, docker, сборка

Решил пощупать Docker-технологию для запуска приложений и в процессе чтения появился вопрос.

В некоторых репозиториях гитхаба видел, что авторы разделяют проект на docker-образ и просто код (типа, mysite.git и mysite-docker.git). Разумно ли это?

Comment: Пожалуйста разделите этот вопрос на несколько разных вопросов. Это поможет дать ответы полезные большему числу людей.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman готово.

Comment: Запуск сайта из Docker-образа VS запуск c традиционными средствами (uWSGI, Nginx, Apache) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611961/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-vs-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-c-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-uwsgi-nginx

Comment: Запуск Docker-образов на боевом сервере http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611957/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5

Comment: Различие между терминами “слой” и “контейнер” в Docker http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611953/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-docker

Comment: Что включать в Docker-образ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612160/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое разделение обычно делают, что бы образы автоматически собирались и выкладывались в реестр на docker.io. В Docker Cloud можно настроить автоматический сбор образа при изменении репозитория на Github/Bitbucket.

Если репозиторий для проекта и для docker образа один и то же, то при каждом push будет запускаться сборка нового docker образа. А это может быть не желательно.

Comment: А если собирать не из любой ветки, а только из релизной?

Comment: да. вы можете настроить сборку из определенной ветки или tag.

Comment: то есть как понимаю, отличий особых нет? если человек хочет сразу запустить приложение он берет докер-образ, если хочет читать код или форкнуть - берет просто проект.

Comment: часто бывает, что проект делает один, а образ другой человек и поэтому различая могут быть. но это достаточно просто выяснить заглянув в dockerfile. образы обычно хранятся в репозитории (registry) docker.io.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman как называть созданный образ. есть рекомендации?

Comment: @while1pass особых рекомендаций не встречал. Есть рекомендации по меткам, но это немного не то.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman видел указывают в названии образ предшественник типа myproject/debian через слеш или myproject-debian или дефис. если я назову my-super-project? или это не принципиально

Comment: @while1pass слэш в имени может указывать, что данный образ будет залит не в реестр docker.io, а какой-то другой, так же это может указывать на имя пользователя который создал этот образ. например один мой образ называется vaysman/dnsdock:1.0 и вы его можете скачать с docker.io используя именно это имя.

Comment: возможно я задам глупый вопрос. но образ представляет какую-то физическую сущность, типа, картинки jpeg или образа iso? допустим, я создал свой образ командой "docker build...", он есть в списке "docker images". куда дальше? в docker.io? могу отправить в репозиторий?

Comment: да. вы можете его поместить в реестр используя команду `docker push`. вы можете поднять свой реестр и хранить образы там. может использовать один из публичных.