# Запуск Docker-образов на боевом сервере

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, docker, сборка

Имеется веб-сайт на Django, на боевом сервере для запуска использую связку uWSGI/Nginx, локальная разработка - virtualenv/dev-сервер Django

Решил пощупать Docker-технологию для запуска приложений и в процессе чтения появился вопрос.

Если я создам Docker-образ проекта, смогу я его запустить на привычной связке uWSGI/Nginx? Или же мои файлы будут "спрятаны" внутри Docker-образа, как в черном ящике, и доступны только через специфические команды?

Comment: относитесь к докеру, как к маленькой виртуальной машине/vps. Если Вы можете реализовать свою идею на группе vps, Вы скорее всего сделаете это в докере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши сервисы со всеми зависимостями будут упакованы в контейнер и изолированы от остальных процессов на системе в которой вы запустите контейнер. Но вы можете настроить контейнер и хост-систему так, что часть файлов будет доступна вне контейнера.

Контейнеризация обеспечивает удобное распространение вашего сервиса и простоту запуска.

В вашем случае внутри контейнера будут - uWSGI/Nginx (хотя это опционально), Python, Django и ваш собственный код. Наружу контейнер будет выставлять несколько портов - 80, 443. Плюс вам надо будет добавить связь (link) к контейнеру с БД (хотя БД может быть и не в контейнере)

Вы сможете запустить этот контейнер на любой системе (максимально "голой") на которой установлен Docker. Docker - это единственная зависимость.

Comment: то есть в привычном понимании дерева каталогов и файлов не будет, мы допустим, на 80 порт контейнера будем отправлять запрос и получать ответ?

Comment: "часть файлов" - вы сейчас о пробросе файлов говорите?

Comment: файлы и каталоги никуда не денутся, просто они будут на "отдельном" диске. вы так же можете смонтировать внутрь контейнера директорию/файл хост-системы и/или volume другого контейнера.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне прям новый мир открываете. Мы можем положить БД в образ? и почему вы сказали "добавить связь (link) к контейнеру с БД"? разве БД не находится на хосте или в самом же контейнере?

Comment: тут еще вопрос появился. Что включать в Docker-образ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612160/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7