# Что включать в Docker-образ

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, docker, сборка

Имеется веб-сайт на Django, на боевом сервере для запуска использую связку uWSGI/Nginx, локальная разработка - virtualenv/dev-сервер Django

Из некоторых вопросов, которые задал на SO:

1. [Распространение Docker-образов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611927/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2)
2. [Запуск Docker-образов на боевом сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611957/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)
3. [Запуск сайта из Docker-образа VS запуск c традиционными средствами (uWSGI, Nginx, Apache)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611961/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-vs-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-c-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-uwsgi-nginx)

появилось еще пара.

**Что включать в образ Docker?**

Мы имеем production-версию и developer-версию. Как понимаю, в репозиториях распространяют production.

Имеет ли смысл создавать docker-образ для developer-версии (применительно ко мне, код проекта и виртуальное окружение virtualenv)? Или разработчику достаточно только кода из репозитория, чтобы начать разработку?

**Где создают docker-образ production-версии?**

На боевом сервере имеется проект, который работает на указанной связке - uwsgi/nginx/упаковщик с production-настройками. Собирать образ я должен на боевом сервере?

Comment: Разницы между production и не production быть не должно. В этом весь смысл. Вернее нет такого разделения. Есть деление на версии софта.

Comment: И то же самое верно про тестирование. Ваши тестировщики будут очень рады тестировать именно ту версию, которая будет на продакшене.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman так, примерно понимаю. то есть мне заранее минифицировать и сшивать проект локально. но что делать со статикой? локально этим занимается дев-сервер Джанго, на продакшне - nginx. статика на продакш собирается, на локале - прям из папок берется

Comment: Что бы не делать ошибок образы собирает робот. Он берет данные из строго определённых мест и собирает образ по строго определённому сценарию. Желательно версии внешних зависимостей тоже контролировать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, понял. вы, кажется, в одном из ответов упоминали тестирование. но сразу же появляется вопрос. что делать со статикой, к примеру? локально этим занимается дев-сервер Джанго, на продакшне - nginx. статика на продакш собирается, на локале - прям из папок берется

Comment: @while1pass вы можете в Django отключить раздачу статики. И поставить перед Django Nginx который статику будет раздавать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman могу. идею понял

Comment: Для вдохновения можно посмотреть демонстрацию того, как на гитлабе автоматизированно собирается докер-образ. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0nYHPue5RU

Comment: @while1pass лучше конечно в образ больше одного сервиса не класть, но это рекомендация, а не требование.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, видел рекомендацию. споров много. веб-сайт считается одним сервисом? его целиком кладут в образ со всеми зависимыми продуктами (api, например)?

Comment: @while1pass я сейчас соберусь с мыслями и напишу ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вообще отлично!

Comment: @MikhailVaysman уточнение по сборке. лучшим вариантом для меня будет такой? получить чистый образ системы, добавить в него nginx, uwsgi, git, стянуть код проекта из репозитория, собрать проект как на продакшне, настроить uwsgi/nginx на продакш и работать с этим образом.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman или в чистый образ добавить мой проект. затем скачать образы чистых систем с отдельными сервисами (nginx, uwsgi), настроить их для работы с моим сервисом и заставить работать с образом моего проекта. как-то сложно второй вариант получается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не должно быть понятия production и non-production версия образа. Разработчики, тестировщики, эксплуатационники и все остальные должны использовать одну и туже версию образа.

Процесс разработки может быть устроен совершенно по разному, но если используется docker-образ (например, сервер разрабатываемый другой группой) в качестве внешней зависимости, то он должен браться из того же источника, что и для других нужд - тестирование, эксплуатация и т.п.

**Как, где и чем создают docker-образы?**

Процесс изготовления образа должен быть полностью автоматизирован, что бы избежать ошибок и сделать процесс повторяемым.

Приблизительно процесс изготовления образа выглядит так (я опускаю некоторые шаги):

1. Разработчик дописал код и протестировал его локально, в том числе и сборку образа.
2. Разработчик заливает код в систему контроля версий.
3. Робот собирает проект и создает артефакты для развертывания (мнифицирует все, объединяет в общий пакет и т.п.).

   1. Необязательный шаг - артефакты помещаются в хранилище.
4. Робот собирает docker-образ.

   1. Необязательный шаг - робот подписывает образ.
5. Робот заливает образ в реестр.

Если нет специфических требовани, то для управления процессом создания можно использовать любой **Continuous Integration** сервер - **Jenkins**, **TeamCity**, **Bamboo** и т.д. У них у всех есть соответсвующие плагины или можно написать простые шел-скрипты и создавать образы стандартной командой `docker build`.

**Что включать в docker-образ?**

Сложно дать однозначный ответ на этот вопрос, так как многое зависит от типа образа и личных предпочтений. Я напишу как бы я поступил с сервером на **Django**.

Я мало работал с **Django**, так что поправьте меня, если я говорю что-то несоответствующее действительности.

Если проект только начинается и нагрузка на сервис будет маленькая, то я бы поместил все (кроме БД) в один образ. Т.е. образ будет содержать:

- **Python** фиксированной версии установленный как системный (без **virtualenv** и пр)
- **nginx/Apache** фиксированных версий с нужными настройками
- собственно ваше приложение, взятое как артефакт для развертывания и развернутое внутри образа

БД либо в отдельный образ, либо на отдельный сервер без использования контейнерезации. Если БД идёт отдельным образом, то **важно** позаботится о сохранении данных на внешний (по отношению к контейнеру) раздел диска. В противном случае данные будут утеряны при перезапуске контейнера.

Если нагрузка будет значительная и есть много статических страниц, то я бы сделал несколько образов:

1. Образ со статическими страницами

   - **nginx/Apache**
   - статическая часть вашего приложения
2. Образ с динамической частью

   - **Python**
   - часть вашего приложения (**Django**)
3. Образ балансировщиком (необязательный)

   - **nginx/HAProxy/Varnish/etc**

Если проект очень большой, то возможно статическую и динамическую часть делают разные команды и в этом случае они и буду отвечать за подготовку `Dockerfile` к своей части проекта.

Comment: заранее задам вопрос, какие есть инструменты для автоматического создания образа? сейчас первый образ буду собирать вручную,  о на будущее нужно знать

Comment: отметил ответом, вы очень полезно отвечаете. ну, и жду продолжения)

Comment: прошу прощенья - отвлекся на Шерлока :) но теперь дописал.

Comment: какой поворот с "Восточным ветром")

Comment: "БД либо в отдельный образ..." ну, если я вложу БД в образ, как понимаю, критической ошибки не будет?

Comment: "... либо на отдельный сервер." под отдельным сервером вы подразумеваете продакшн-сервер, на котором будет запущен докер, или любой сервер с базой, к которой обращается приложение?

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения

Comment: @while1pass я обновил ответ.